# Luau Couroutine stopping thread

Tags: lua, coroutine

I'm trying to make a OnChange Event Listener, I thought of using coroutines to poll the value in a loop, and see if it changed, so

```
function Changed(Value)
    local StartingValue = Value
    while true do
        if StartingValue ~= Value then
            print(Value)
            StartingValue = Value
            break
        end
    end
end
local n = 0
local co = coroutine.wrap(function()
    Changed(n)
    coroutine.yield()
end)
co()

n = (n + 1)
print("Script ended")
```

Is the Code I thought of for now, But it gets stuck in the Coroutine.. nothing happens after `co()`

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Changed()` never returns.

At the very beginning you're assigning the `Value` to the `StartingValue`, and the `break` is inside of the `if` statement that is only executed when the values are different. But they're not because of that initial assignment. So you have the infinite loop that has no means of ending.